# Behavior of entropy under convolutions of random walk operator on a finitely generated group?

Tags: group-theory, convolution, random-walk, entropy, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group with generating set $S=\{s_1,s_2,....,s_n\}$. Let $\mu$ be a uniform probability distribution on $S$. We can define a random walk $X_n$ on $G$ by declaring that $\mu$ is the law/step distribution for the random walk. Then the n'th convolution $\mu^{*n}$ is the distribution for $X_n$ (this is the simple random walk on $G$ for $\mu$ uniform). For any distribution $\mu$ on $G$, we can define its entropy as: $H(\mu)=\sum_{x\in G}\mu(x)log(\mu(x))$. I'm wondering if anyone knows anything about how $H(\mu^{*n})$ behaves? I'm most interested in equalities/inequalities relating $\mu^{*n}$ to $\mu$ or $\mu^{*k}$, $k\neq n$.

Comment: You always have $H(\mu^{*n}) \le nH(\mu)$. I feel like this is sharp up to multiplicative constants. If $G$ is the free group on two generators, say $a,b$, and $S = \{a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}\}$, then after $n$ steps, the entropy should be at least $cn$ I feel like. I am not too well-versed in this area though..

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned that I did know that bound already. I would really like some way of comparing $\mu^{*n}$ and $\mu^{*k}$, but I did not specify that so if no one else answers I'll give it to you

Comment: can you be more precise about what you want? An inequality relating $\mu^{*n}$ and $\mu^{*k}$ for any fixed $k,n$ and every $\mu$? I don't think such a thing will exist. Or do you want a bound relating $\mu^{*n}$ and $\mu^{*k}$ for fixed $\mu$ and large $k,n$?